# Tyepescript how to filter an array of objects depending on a specific property exists or not

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am try to filter objects depending on if they have a certain property.

Example:

```
objectArray = [{a: "", b: ""}, {a: ""}]
objectArray.filter( obj => "b" in obj ).forEach(obj => console.log(**obj.b**))
```

typescript complains about the obj.b, since some objects doesn't have the b property, but since I filter them out it shouldn't. What am I doing/getting wrong.

Comment: The error you are getting is because of the **. What are those

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/mqQXqm) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Answer (score 1):

Declare `objectArray` in the same statement where it is initialized (with `let` or `const`). This will allow TypeScript to infer the type of the expression `objectArray.filter( obj => "b" in obj )` correctly, i.e.

```
const objectArray = [{a: "", b: ""}, {a: ""}];
objectArray.filter( obj => "b" in obj ).forEach(obj => console.log(obj.b)); // no error
```

[**Playground link**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArApsKBBATpghgTxgF4YBtAbxwC4YAiGgGhnmroF9GKWbWBdAbgBQCFGiy48AOgBmASwA2UZJgAUcJEQB8teDRgywaxDACU0kJgCiOYAAtlwzTFCQQc5BLkgA5vaQT4xsaCQA)

Answer (score -1):

Objects.keys can help you

```
objectArray.filter(x=> Object.keys(x).indexOf('b')>=0 );
```

Comment: This a) doesn't solve the problem and b) is significantly slower and more convoluted than the OP's code. The `in` operator is both highly optimized and generally recognized as a type-narrowing check by the Typescript compiler, your version requires constructing an array and then linearly traversing it, meaning `O(n^2)`, and is not one of the mechanisms the compiler uses to narrow the type of a value.